# Objective-C didSelectRowAtIndexPath and serge to view controller

Tags: objective-c

I am using a UITableViewController and didSelectRowAtIndexPath like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *type = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Type"];

if([type isEqualTOString: @"PDF"]){

   //GOTO View Controller

}else{


    NSArray *elements = [[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"FTP\\"];

    currentPath = [[[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"FTP\\"] lastObject];

    NSString *escapedString = [elements[1] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];


    self.tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetFilesAndDirectories:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",escapedString]];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

  }
}
```

is what I am trying to do possible? If the type is PDF goto the view Controller, else just update the table view.

Currently, When I select a row, it goes to View Controller, everytime.

This is what I got:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *type = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Type"];

    if([type  isEqualToString: @"Directory"]){

        NSArray *elements = [[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"FTP\\"];

        currentPath = [[[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"FTP\\"] lastObject];

        NSString *escapedString = [elements[1] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

        self.tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetFilesAndDirectories:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",escapedString]];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }else{

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self.view];

    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Here");
    }
}
```

But it still goes to the View Controller everytime.

Comment: Log your type value: NSLog(@"type: %@", type);

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
In the PDF if you should Create the view controller you want to present and then call the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the current view controller, passing in the PDF view controller you want.

**EDIT:** I didn't see the edited last sentence.
The only issue i found is a misstype in isEqualToString function and the chance that your type string could be nil.

**EDIT 2:**
I add an example of my own code. In this case the view allways open, but its different depending of the content if.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    locationData *locData;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        locData= [self.sortEDlocations objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else {
        if(_btnUrgentCareFilter.isSelected){
            locData = [self.filterSortOtherLocations objectAtIndex:row];
        }else{
            locData = [self.sortOtherLocations objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }

    [self showDetailView:locData];

}
```

Comment: can I get an example of this?>

Comment: your example does not help, all I can see from this is method calls.